# Utilizing scientific notation: change distance in light years to distance in miles

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A light year, the distance light travels in 1 year, is approximately 5.9 x 10 ^12 miles. The Andromeda galaxy is approximately 1.7 x 10^6 light-years from our galaxy. Find the distance in miles between our galaxy and the Andromeda galaxy.

I do not know how to approach this problem.

Comment: I don't see the connection to abstract algebra.

Comment: algebra-precalculus. Anyway, this is just unit conversion: lightyears times miles/lightyear = miles, because the lightyears cancel out. It's no different from grams/mL times mL = grams.

Comment: I looked through the tags and saw one for "arithemtic", and since this is an arithmetic word problem, I'd go with arithmetic.

Comment: It is actually a problem dealing with exponents, thus Algebra.

Comment: Say no to the imperial system :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance between the galaxies is
$$1.7 \times {10}^6 \;\; \text{light-years} \;\; = \;\; (1.7 \times {10}^6 \;\; \text{light-years})\left(\frac{5.9 \times {10}^{12} \text{ miles}}{1 \text{ light-year}}\right)$$
$$=\;\; (1.7 \times {10}^6)(5.9 \times {10}^{12}) \;\; \text{miles}$$
$$= \;\; (1.7)(5.9) \times {10}^{6+12} \;\; \text{miles}$$
$$= \;\; 10 \times {10}^{18} \;\; \text{miles} \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{(to two significant digits)}$$
$$ = \;\; {10}^{19} \;\; \text{miles}$$

The google search ["unit conversion" {AND} "multiply by 1"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unit+conversion%22+%22multiply+by+1%22) should also be helpful.

Comment: In the book the answer is 1.003 x 10^19 miles

Comment: Oops, I used $5.9 \times {10}^9$ (incorrect) instead of $5.9 \times {10}^{12}$ (correct).